# modulo of a set value

Tags: visual-studio-2013, modulo

The function that I am having a problem with is below, Visual studio is saying that "expression must be a modifiable value". Is there something that I am doing wrong, or is it a problem with the compiler? Thank you for any help/suggestions.

```
int primeCheck(int number){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++){
        if (number % i = 0){//the error is coming up with the number variable here
            count++;
        };
    };
    if (count > 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign 0 to number % i.. Use '==' not =

Comment: yeah, thank you the == works, I just didn't see it while reviewing it myself.